# Images won't stay horizontal, they stack as 2 rows

Tags: jquery, css, html

http://boomboomdesigns.com/nomoon/index.html
This is the page in question.
I've tried modifying the CSS of the header element to increase the page width, but that makes it move to the right.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but I'm trying to get the Sanctis and the Coming soon images to all be on one line horizontally.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/dePc9qRR

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: The images are stacking because the containing element's width is forcing them to. Make the element wider, and the images won't stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track... Just increase the header width, but also decrease the margin-left attribute as well. These values worked for me:

```
padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
top: 25%;
width: 1100px;
height: 300px;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -150px;
margin-left: -550px;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **float**, you would probably want to use **flex** feature from CSS. It will solve your issue with proper alignment. See the link below on how to use it.

[Flex tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Jonny Dee,
You have some coding errors that we should fix first.

First of all, the `<br />` tag is self closing, meaning there is no `</br>` tag.

Second of all, in some of you `<li></li>`'s, you didn't have a closing `<a>` tag before the closing `</li>` tag.

You essentially have the right code to make the images align side-by-side, you just need to change the `display: inline` to `display: inline-block`. Then it will work.

I also suggest that you move your CSS to an external file. This way, the webpage will load faster and not lag as much.

If you fix your errors and change the CSS to `display: inline-block`, it should work.

Hope this helps!
Good luck.